# Intermittent ORA-22288 error - command length incorrect

Tags: oracle, file-io, plsql

I have an intermittent problem with a web application that frequently has to open a file located on the database server as part of regular operations.  For the vast majority of the time, this functions without issue, however, at seemingly random times, the corresponding requests start returning HTTP 400 errors.  Bouncing the apache server addresses the issue for a time, but it invariably returns in a day or at most a week.

I added some logging to the relevant pl/sql code (no, don't run away! come back!), which I've listed below for reference:

```
declare
  bl_blob blob;
  bf_file bfile := bfilename(<directory that totally exists>, <file that totally exists>);
begin
  dbms_lob.createTemporary(bl_blob, true);
  dbms_lob.open(bf_file, dbms_lob.lob_readonly);
  dbms_lob.open(bl_blob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  dbms_lob.loadfromfile(bl_blob, bf_file, dbms_lob.getLength(bf_file));
  dbms_lob.close(bf_file);
  return bl_blob;
end;
```

It turns out the 400 errors correspond to the following ORA-22288 error:

```
file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect
```

My question is, why would the operation suddenly, and repeatedly, start erroring out where previously the same file could be opened without issue?  The underlying file is never changed and only ever opened programmatically with read only permissions.

All the forum digging I've done so far has yielded mostly a slew of "turn it off and on" solutions, which...yeah.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Too many open files ? A missing `close`  somewhere ?

Comment: It looks like Oracle may just be passing through an error from the operating system.  Googling "The program issued a command but the command length is incorrect" leads me to believe this is a Windows problem.  Can you add the host OS and OS version?

Comment: @JonHeller Yeah, I'd read many forum posts saying that, though I haven't yet seen any specific mention of a relevant underlying cause.  Regardless, here are the OS specifics: Windows Server 2003 x64 SP 2

Comment: Just for investigation: catch the exception and print the stack trace (`dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace`) to know which line exactly raises the error. And wrap the entire thing into loop to retry once or twice - it can be useful to know if the immediate retry works or not.

Comment: Also curious that bouncing Apache resolves a DB issue - or are you using mod_plsql? Not sure how the two would be related anyway.

Comment: To clarify, your web app is running PL/SQL on the DB server and there is a file also located on the DB server (not on a mount), which the PL/SQL is opening? If this were a mount of some description then I would guess that you've got a slightly dodgy network...

Comment: Should you have `dbms_lob.close(bl_blob);` in there too? You're opening up 2 objects but only closing one.

Comment: Can't explain, but a possible solution might be to put the file contents into a table and to run a query against the table instead of opening a file?

Comment: Have you considered the Oracle parameter for max number of open files https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams219.htm#REFRN10196

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the code you're running, or if you've simplified it for SO. Your bfile is basically a pointer, so I'm not sure what happens if the file is modified on disk after you establish the pointer. I'm also not sure if anonymous blocks like this get parsed and cached in the same way as SQL statements. Long story short, try this:

```
declare
  bl_blob blob;
  bf_file bfile;
begin
  bf_file := bfilename(<directory that totally exists>, <file that totally exists>);
  dbms_lob.createTemporary(bl_blob, true);
  dbms_lob.open(bf_file, dbms_lob.lob_readonly);
  dbms_lob.open(bl_blob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  dbms_lob.loadfromfile(bl_blob, bf_file, dbms_lob.getLength(bf_file));
  dbms_lob.close(bf_file);
  return bl_blob;
end;
```

Comment: Most folks should consider anonymous PL/SQL block statements just like any other type of SQL statement. You can't FETCH from a cursor parsed with an anonymous PL/SQL block but their cursor has to go through the PARSE and EXEC dbcall code just like any other cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `dbms_lob.getLength(bf_file)` for the amount to be loaded, please try using `DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE`. This may help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't note (or I don't see) your app server's framework but if you're fortunate enough to be running java on your app server, you can simplify your code considerably. I don't know if that will fix your problem but it will at least get rid of the need to know the length of the bfile.

```
public void getFile (String oradir, String filename, String filesysdir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException, Exception {
    CallableStatement s = this.conn.prepareCall("select bfilename(?,?) from dual");
    s.setString(1, oradir);
    s.setString(2, filename);
    OracleResultSet r = (OracleResultSet) s.executeQuery();
    if (r.next())
        saveBFILE(r.getBFILE(1), filesysdir);
}

private void saveBFILE (BFILE b, String dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
    b.openFile();
    InputStream s = b.getBinaryStream();
    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(s);
    String name = b.getName();
    String path = dir == null ? name : dir + '/' + name;
    System.out.println("creating " + name);
    FileOutputStream w = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
    int nb;
    byte[] ba = new byte[4096];
    while ((nb = s.read(ba)) != -1)
        w.write(ba, 0, nb);
    w.close();
    b.closeFile();
}
```