# Oracle Lob Operation FILEOPEN Failed I/O Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, file-io, lob

I have an issues where my DBMS_LOB open operation which falls over where by I receive the following error message.

[image]

I have double checked the file exists, that the permission on the file are open to everyone one on the destination server, the database user has full access to the Oracle Directory.

I have seen similar issues where by it states that the file does not exist or the directory is invalid but I have not seen an I/O error before.

Any guidance is appreciated, I have been on the server where the file is located and I can't see what might be a miss based on the error message as the file definitely exists.

Oracle version is 11.2 trying to read from a windows server 2019.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Is the entire OS directory path also open to the Oracle OS user? Also is this a single node or RAC - and if RAC is the directory and file present on all nodes?

Comment: Hi, Single Node.

Comment: I think that I've seen something about it saying like:    
"Oracle does not support hard link! When I remove the hard link and
make a copy of the file, the procedure works"

There is also something (not the same - but similar) about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913032/intermittent-ora-22288-error-command-length-incorrect